Crop arbitrary areas of GeoTIFF raster file
I have ~100 raster map GeoTIFF files with unimportant data around their edges and some (mostly rectangular) insets, which I would like to crop from the files before applying further processing. I am using GDAL command line tools.
The data around the edges is easy: I can just use gdal_translate with an appropriately sized -srcwin to discard the edges. I would like to do the same thing with the insets: Crop them out of the final raster dataset, filling them with nodata. I know the pixel positions and sizes of each inset, but I don't know what tool can do this.
I see that gdalwarp has a -cutline option that I could pass a shapefile to, describing the shapes of the insets, but I know the location/size of the insets in pixels, not in the coordinate system that the data is in, so I don't think that would be the appropriate way to do this.
Maybe I am missing something obvious. Is there a way to just fill an arbitrary pixel rectangle (or polygon) with nodata, specified in pixels?

Just using command line tools I don't think this can be done. Do you have any python abilities?

Yes, I'm proficient with Python, was just hoping I could do this whole thing in a single shell script. I'd accept a Python answer if that's the only way to do the job.

Thinking out loud in the comments here, if I could generate a separate raster for each input, that contains either 0 or 1 and somehow treat it as a mask. That might get me closer.
https://gdal.org/en/stable/development/rfc/rfc15_nodatabitmask.html
